How to build a point cloud of the environment in nvidia isaac sim such as the env “small warehouse with multiple shelves”?
Does Isaac Sim provide some off-the-shelf solution to get a point cloud map of the entire environment?
Does anyone have a good idea? For example, traversing all objects in the entire space, or setting up a robot with a LiDAR sensor
